# Mac osx terminal merge folders (rsync?)

Tags: macos, air, terminal

I have 2 folders that I would like to merge, the root is AIR3SDK which has subfolders such as frameworks, lib, bin etc. The folder I would like to merge into it is named AIR SDK which also includes subfolders some with the same names as the root folder and some are new.

I would like to override all file that are different in the root folder with the new one (not override the whole folder but check and see which files are different). if its a new file that only exists in AIR SDK then I would like it to be copied to the proper folder.

I have tried rsync -r "AIR SDK" "AIR3SDK"    but it only copies the AIR SDK folder into the AIR3SDK folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you can do that by using

```
cp -Rp "AIR SDK/" AIR3SDK
```

It will copy the contents of AIR SDK into AIR3SDK, replacing any files present in both directory structures with the version from AIR SDK. Documentation for the `cp` command is here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_cp.htm

If the copy was successful, you can remove AIR SDK with

```
rm -rf "AIR SDK/"
```

Documentation here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rm.htm

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution (add sudo for permission that was requested) , this resulted with the same result of the "air sdk" folder copied into the air3sdk folder as a whole folder. The result i am looking for is having all the folders and files inside of "air sdk" folder copied (and replacing files with same name) into air3sdk    Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the first command was missing a `/`. Depending on your user rights, you need to work with `sudo`, of course.